# How to make the label text bold in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, fonts, pysimplegui

for example

```
label = sg.Text("Hello World", font="Helvetica")
```

How to make this text **Bold** ?

Also, is there any source that all of the supporting fonts by PySimpleGUI are mentioned?

Comment: You can use the font parameter

Answer (score 1):

The `font` parameter can be used to specify a `bold font`

for example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

label = sg.Text("Hello World", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"))

layout = [[label]]

window = sg.Window("My Window", layout)
event, values = window.read()
window.close()
```

For the supported fonts, you can go to https://www.cssfontstack.com/ to see a list of the most used